# How can I interpret the following sentence?

Tags: interpretation

My land lord sent me ("he" in the following sentence) and my roommate ("you" in the following sentence) the following sentence.

Although I can understand it by context, I don't know exactly what it means.

> He will pay you the $999 per his current game plan with Zelle transfers to you.

How can I interpret the above sentense?

FYI, I can transfer up to $500 a day through Zelle, so I'm trying to send the money to my roommate over two days. Then, my roommate will send it to my land lord. This is the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He will pay you the $999 per his current game plan with Zelle transfers to you.

I'd break up the sentence like this:

He will pay you the $999 | per his current game plan | with Zelle transfers to you.

So OP (he) will pay you (the roommate) the $999 with Zelle transfers. The "per his current game plan" refers to the current plan and course of action.

Comment: I think "he" is the OP the quote.

Comment: Yes “he” is me. Haha

Comment: Why did he say “game”? Actually it is not a game.

Comment: Fixed “he”. Also, “game plan” is really just an expression.